# How to Cite an Author Who Has a Pen Name

Tags: style, citations

If both the author's name and the pen name are known, should one cite by one name or both names? If one, which?

Comment: What style guide are you following? (APA, Chicago, etc.) Is this an academic/technical or popular article?

Answer (score 12):

David Becker has written about APA citations for pseudonyms.

> Citing pseudonyms can seem tricky at first, but it becomes much simpler when you take into account one of APA Style’s key mottos: Cite what you see.  When it comes to citing an author, cite whatever name is used by the source, whether it be a real name or a pseudonym.  For example, The Adventures of Tom Sawyer lists Mark Twain as its author, not Samuel Clemens, so you should cite the author’s pseudonym rather than his real name.

The [full article](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2012/02/how-to-cite-pseudonyms.html) deals with other peculiarities like titles (Dalai Lama) and how to distinguish Dr Seuss from Theodor Geissel.